# Most simple-graphs lack a cartesian quotient?

Tags: limits, graph-theory, inverse, products

It seems that most small simple-graphs cannot be made by multiplying smaller simple graphs using cartesian multiplication, with the exception of products involving the trivial single node graph.

A more concise way of saying this could be that most have no cartesian quotient that is also a simple-graph. Or further more that most simple-graphs are (cartesian) prime.

However a large proportion of single digit natural numbers are prime while the density of prime numbers tends towards 0 as the magnitude of the numbers being considered tends towards infinity.

---

Does the density of "cartesian prime" simple-graphs also decrease as the number of nodes in the graph increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's $$2^{\binom{n}{2}}$$ labeled $n$-vertex graphs, which has exponent $\sim n^2/2$, and $$\prod_{\substack{d \text{ divides } n\\d \not\in \{1,n\}}} 2^{\binom{d}{2}+\binom{n/d}{2}} \leq n2^{2\binom{n/2}{2}} \leq 2^{n^2/4+\log_2(n)}$$ labeled $n$-vertex [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) graphs, which has exponent $\sim n^2/4$ (excluding things like $K_1 \Box G$).

Thus, almost all graphs are "Cartesian primes".

We shouldn't expect primes and Cartesian primes to behave the same: the number of numbers in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ grows linearly with $n$, whereas the number of $n$-vertex graphs grows exponential polynomially.  Their behaviors are probably largely unrelated.

---

By the way, for unlabelled graphs, the number of $n$-vertex graphs is no more than
$$
\frac{1}{n!}2^{\binom{n}{2}} \sim 2^{n^2/2-n\ln n+n-O(\ln n)}
$$
by [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which doesn't change much.

Comment: Thank you. An enlightening answer, even if there being fewer of such primes would be more exciting (factors, division, 3n+1 problem, etc...)